# Coffee Script ,backbone - - escape '@' character , instead of reading it as 'this'

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I am trying to save email like example@gmail.com to the **model**  and then save to the server using backbone.
When i am sending normal words like "sdnfkjs" , it is saving correctly and sending model to server.
But when i am sending "example@gmail.com" it is saying "400 Bad Request" with the url like this :->
...test/contact_email/sdf@hjkg.com/tid/2924 400 Bad Request

What should be the reason ?
Thanks

Comment: How are you making the request? Special characters in a URL need to be escaped. something like jquery will do this for you.

Comment: working ! just encode the email address , i mean replace that @ with some other character like ; and decode that in the backend.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use with the built in Javascript encoder/decoder :

```
encodeURIComponent("example@gmail.com") // returns "example%40gmail.com"
decodeURIComponent("example%40gmail.com") // returns "exampl@gmail.com"
```